# How to calculate covariance of X and Y

Tags: probability, random-variables

There are two random variables X and Y which take on value {-1,0,1} and have the following joint distribution

[image: Joint Distribution]

How can i calculate Covariance and Correlation between X and Y
Note: i don't actually know how to even start calculating. I saw that Cov(X,y) is E[(x - E[x])(Y-E[y])^T]. but, how can i get E[x] and x from that table. How to read that table. and what does the transpose mean, should i transpose the matrix and then calculate the value?

Comment: At least you should add your own thinking and trying on this. If that lacks then implicitly you ask for downvoting and closing.

Comment: @drhab, i have edited the question

Comment: This is the joint distribution of $2$ random variables. The fact that you see a "matrix" seems to confuse you, and might make you think that you are dealing with random vectors. That is not the case hence you can "forget" about the transpose sign. That only applies on random vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table gives you information about the distribution of $(X,Y)$ which includes information about $X$ and $Y$ separately..

For instance you can read that $$P(X=-1)=P(X=-1,Y=-1)+P(X=-1,Y=0)+P(X=-1,Y=1)=0+0+\frac13=\frac13$$

Likewise you can find $P(X=0)$ and $P(X=1)$ and then you can go on with $$\mathbb EX=(-1)\cdot P(X=-1)+0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)$$

Again likewise you can find $\mathbb EY$ and also $\mathbb EXY$ (do you see how?).

After that you can find the covariance on base of $$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb EXY-\mathbb EX\mathbb EY\tag1$$
Here $(1)$ can be deduced from the definition:$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb E(X-\mathbb EX)(Y-\mathbb EY)$$

Comment: Just one thing, so, E[XY] will be P(XY)*X*Y?

Comment: $XY$ can take $3$ values here: $1$, $-1$ and $0$. Find the probabilities and calculate $\mathbb EXY=(-1)\cdot P(XY=-1)+0\cdot P(XY=0)+1\cdot P(XY=1)$.

Comment: Also $EXY=\sum_{(x,y)}xyP(X=x,Y=y)$ where $(x,y)$ ranges over the set $\{-1,0,1\}^2$.

Comment: so, how to handle it when x=1 and y=-1, there will be one more expression right..@drhab

Comment: like (1)*(-1) P(X=1 , Y=-1) = -1 * 1/3 = -1/3

Comment: so, in a way, i have to handle all the possible combinations of X and Y?

Comment: There are two ways leading to the same result. I gave both in separate comments. All combinations are handled.

Comment: @drhab I have calculated the covariance. It is zero, isn't it? As E(XY) and E(X) is 0.

Comment: $EXY=(-1)\cdot1\cdot\frac13+1\cdot(-1)\cdot\frac 13+0\cdot0\cdot\frac13=-\frac23$